# A quick question about responsiveness in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, flutter-layout, responsiveness

I'm almost finishing to implement my app and now I'm making it more responsive but I found a problem. I'm using three emulators(Pixel 2, Pixel 4 and Nexus 4) plus my phone(Galaxy S10+). Here is the issue:

[image] [image]

The first one on the left is my emulator(Pixel 4) and second one on the right is my phone(S10+). See the problem? The position changed somehow and both have the same aspect ratio(19:9) and default resolution(1080x2280). So what is going on here? I will put the code for only one image(that sphere with the magnifier thing, if works to one it will for the rest):

```
 body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Stack(children: [
              Container(
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight <= 592
                      ? constraints.maxHeight * 3.6
                      : constraints.maxHeight * 2.7,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/SdLahrV.png'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover))),
              Wrap(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: constraints.maxWidth >= 380 &&
                                constraints.maxHeight >= 500
                            ? constraints.maxWidth * 0.02
                            : constraints.maxWidth * 0.04,
                        top: constraints.maxHeight >= 592
                            ? constraints.maxHeight * 0.22
                            : constraints.maxHeight * 0.35),
                    height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.14,
                    width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.24,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/HmwwpOb.gif')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
           ),
          ),
        );
       }
      );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Media queries can be helpful in this case.

Comment: I didn't go to Media Query but I will give it a try. I thought constraintedBox and MediaQuery do the same thing, that's why I didn't use this yet. Thanks